# XAML -> C# Update a Text property from Resources in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

I had a TextBlock in Xaml to display a title. I used to set a `x:Uid="MyTitle"`, describe in a resources file. But now, my title can change. I try to bind on a title variable in my .cs (and we can't bind on a x:Uid).

So ! I try to change my title directly on the C# and... I failed.
Here's my idee :

**My Tree**

```
Root
 Source
  -code.xaml
  -code.xaml.cs
 Resources
  En
   -resources.resw
     "Mytitle_1.Text", "This is my first title"
     "Mytitle_2.Text", "This is the other one"
```

**code.xaml**

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" x:Name="Exemples" FontSize="20" Margin="20, 0, 20, 0" LineHeight="25" MaxLines="2" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" Height="65"/>
```

**code.xaml.cs**

```
private string GetResources(string key)
{
   ResourceLoader rl = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView("../Resources");
   string resources = rl.GetString(key);

   return resources;
}

private void ChangeTitle()
{
  if (something)
   Exemples.Text = GetResources("Mytitle_1");
  else
   Exemples.Text = GetResources("Mytitle_2");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the problem. I just use my key like "Mytitle_1" or "Mytitle_1.Text".

All I needed is that :

```
private string GetResources(string key)
{
   ResourceLoader rl = ResourceLoader("../Resources");
   string resources = rl.GetString(key);

   return resources;
}

private void ChangeTitle()
{
   if (something)
   Exemples.Text = GetResources("Mytitle_1/Text");
   else
   Exemples.Text = GetResources("Mytitle_2/text");
}
```

Voila !

Answer (score 0):

```
ResourceLoader loader = new ResourceLoader();

private void ChangeTitle()
{
   if (something)
      Exemples.Text = loader.GetString("MyTextInResources1");
   else
      Exemples.Text = loader.GetString("MyTextInResources2");
 }
```

and in your resources file donot add .Text to your string, it is only added for xaml controls.

so in your resources file 
simply add a new row as

```
MyTextInResources1     your string to be displayed
```

Comment: Yes ! In my solution I forget to change ResourceLoader loader = new ResourceLoader(); I edit yours, you miss a point.